# Quasar Icon Genie CLI crops icons from square to rectangle

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, capacitor, quasar-framework, quasar

How can I omit the cropping? I have an icon 512x512 I pass it to Icon Genie CLI and generate icons for my Capacitor app.
I use the command `icongenie generate -m capacitor -i /path/to/source/icon.png`.
In result I get my icons cropped to rectangle and for ios it has a white background. Here is example of my input (512x512):

[image: Input]

Here is example of my output (AppIcon-512@2x):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this as well.

I used the following flag per the [docs](https://quasar.dev/icongenie/command-list):

```
--skip-trim           Do not trim the icon source file
```

The result matches the expected square input